# jQuery loop through JSON multidimensional array

Tags: jquery

I have a JSON array being returned, and I want to loop through it to display the data in a table:

```
{"confirmed":"362.53","not_confirmed":"9,403.87","payouts":{"confirmed":{"2023-04-05":36253},"submitted":{"2023-04-12":900,"2023-04-11":9600},"pending_submission":{"2023-04-13":897694,"2023-05-04":32193}}}
```

I tried using this for loop inside my ajax call, but what I see in the console is just `Object object`

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: ""
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        for(var i in data.payouts) {
            console.log(data.payouts[i]);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: There's no jQuery here just JavaScript. I also cannot see any arrays anywhere!

Comment: If you see `[Object object]` then your *object* has been coerced to a string.  This might happen if, for example, your console.log was `console.log("payout" + i + ":" + data.payouts[i]))` don't concatenate objects with strings in console.log:  `console.log("payout", i, data.payouts[i])` (and never use alert(obj))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data.payouts` is not an array, it is an object that contains a set of keys and values. To iterate over objects, you can use a method from the `Object` class (docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object).

To iterate over keys and values, fetching both in each iteration, you can use `Object.entries()` like this:

```js
const data = {"confirmed":"362.53","not_confirmed":"9,403.87","payouts":{"confirmed":{"2023-04-05":36253},"submitted":{"2023-04-12":900,"2023-04-11":9600},"pending_submission":{"2023-04-13":897694,"2023-05-04":32193}}};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data.payouts)) {
  console.log(key, "=>", value);
}
```

I used `for..of` to get the values instead of using `for..in` and getting the index of each item in the array returned by the `Object.entries()` method.

Note that the value in every entry is also an object, so you need to use the same logic for each one of them if you want to process them.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `$.each()` function, the code logs a message to the console for each of the nested properties of payouts. Specifically, it logs the value of the confirmed property of that nested object.

**Try below snippet**

```js
let data = { "confirmed": "362.53", "not_confirmed": "9,403.87", "payouts": { "confirmed": { "2023-04-05": 36253 }, "submitted": { "2023-04-12": 900, "2023-04-11": 9600 }, "pending_submission": { "2023-04-13": 897694, "2023-05-04": 32193 } } };
$.each(data, function (index, element) {
    if (index == 'payouts') {
        console.log(element);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```